# Cannot source bash script - unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, shell

I have this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


function onqltrap {
  echo "process with pid $$ was trapped.";
   fle=$(echo "$(pwd)" | tr "/" _);
   rm -f fle;
}

function qltrap {
   trap onqltrap EXIT;
}

function qlstart {
  set -e;
  trap onqltrap EXIT;
  mkdir -p "$HOME/.quicklock/locks"
  fle=$(echo "$(pwd)" | tr "/" _)
  mkdir "$HOME/${fle}.lock" || { echo "quicklock could not acquire lock."; exit 1 }
}

function qlstartold {
   mkdir -p "$HOME/.quicklock/fifo"
   rm "$HOME/.quicklock/fifo/$$.fifo"
   mkfifo "$HOME/.quicklock/fifo/$$.fifo"
}
```

when I source this file in a script, I get this error:

> bash:
>   /Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/quicklock/quicklock-trap.sh:
>   line 28: syntax error: unexpected end of file

does anyone know why that error is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the helpful http://shellcheck.net as strongly recommended in the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) summary, I discovered:

```
Line 19:
  mkdir "$HOME/${fle}.lock" || { echo "quicklock could not acquire lock."; exit 1 }
>>                                                                                ^-- SC1083: This } is literal. Check expression (missing ;/\n?) or quote it.
```

(scroll to the right to see the error.)

In the original output, SC1083 is linked to https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1083 which has more information on the error. What is possibly unclear from the write-up is that the fact that the <kbd>}</kbd> is being treated as a literal argument implies that it is not being treated as the end of the function definition; when the end of the script file is reached, that function is still open.

Comment: my bash plugin did not catch the error - next time I will use spellcheck, fml